# Functions for free and force response

Tags: matlab

I don't know how to determine the free and forced response, using initial conditions and between a certain time for a transfer function. can someone help me?

Comment: Please give us a brief example of your problem and your attempts to solve it and we will be happy to help.

Comment: i did not write any of the code because i dont know which functions to use.the task: i have a transfer function, a vector with the time interval and a vector y with 3 initial conditions

i need the forced and unforced time response of that system

Comment: Follow the solutions my colleagues gave to you in order to fulfill the website's guidelines for a well asked question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague, but for an unforced response of a state-space model you can use `initial(sys,x0,t)` where sys is your models state space, x0 is your vector with initial conditions and `t = ti:ts:tf` where ti is initial time, tf final time and ts is your sample period.

As for the forced one try using `lsim(sys,u,t,x0)`. For more information use the matlab's help